# Adding 2 led flood lights to 15amp breaker

Tags: electrical

I currently have a 15amp circuit that runs outside to a 4 outlet receptacle that was for a

pool pump which is no longer in use. It was run with #8 wires with a #10 ground. I want to

hook up 2 flood lights with 14/3 wire to that circuit. Can I still leave the  4 outlet

receptacle hooked up. I would have to disconnect the #8 wires and run a pigtail back to the

panel. If so would I need to run the pigtail in #8 wire.

I know it would look weird but is it legal

Comment: That's some delightfully overkill wire size for 15 amps. Your question gets confusing when you start talking about pigtails - could you **please clarify** what you are either asking about, or thinking you have to do in that part? ie, I can't see why you'd have to disconnect the wires...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run your 14/3 wire directly from the outlet box to your new lights. You can also leave the outlets connected as the wire from the panel to the outlets is so oversized. Also those two led lights should not add too much load to the existing circuit.